# round numbers back to multiples of 3

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am in a situation where I need to do the following:

```
if n = 0 or 1 or 2; return 0;
if n = 3 or 4 or 5; return 3;
if n = 6 or 7 or 8; return 6;
if n >= 9; return 9
```

I have the following code which is **working fine**.

```
var adjustNumberOfProducts = function(number) {
    var output = 0;
    switch(number) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            output = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            output = 3;
            break;
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            output = 6;
            break;
        default:
            output = 9
            break;
    }
    return output;
}
```

I am wondering if there is more optimal (faster execution) way of doing this.

Comment: Optimal how? speed? readability? Code size? I'd use the `if` logic you have at the top since it would be more readable and less code while the speed of both is pretty much the same. Or you could just return directly from your `switch` blocks instead of assigning to output and `break`ing.

Comment: @nem, mainly script run time.

Comment: Well for one thing, you are potentially evaluating 3 cases instead of 1 `if n < 3 output = 0` etc..

Comment: Too bad JavaScript counts 0 as falsy! `[0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6][number] || 9` would work fine if it was like Ruby and Lua where only `false` and `nil` are `falsy`. :)

Comment: @RayToal: `([1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7][number] || 10) - 1` But don't, please don't. ;-) (Although I **cannot** think why not.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is one of the best comments ive seen in ages!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha yes!

Comment: @RayToal: Ugh, or: `+(["0", "0", "0", 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6][number] || 9)` *(Really...must...stop...)*

Comment: You can use jsperf.com to measure what is actually faster.  I added some of the answers below to this test: http://jsperf.com/round-down-to-nearest

Comment: @T.J. `+(""+[0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6][number] || 9)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going for raw speed, then some kind of lookup is *probably* what you want; however, the usual rules apply: use a profiler.

The lookup that comes to mind is something like the erroneous:

```
// DOES NOT WORK: 0 is falsy in JavaScript
var adjustNumberOfProducts = function (number) {
    return [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6][number] || 9
}
```

But as 0 is falsy in JavaScript, we can use T. J. Crowder's (amusing, not-fully-serious) "adjustment":

```
var adjustNumberOfProducts = function (number) {
    return ([1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7][number] || 10) - 1
}
```

There's a huge readability loss, and many programmers would downright cringe at the sight of this in real code (I think "MY EYES!" might be the modern reaction.)

I think a jsperf test is called for to map this evil approach with your switch statement and the `Math.min(number - (number% 3),9)` technique. I would use some of the asm.js techniques, such as bitwise-oring with zero to force integer math too, to see if that may help (though it may not).

Comment: Looks like it's a winner, but only barely.  Might be worth the extra readability to use another approach... http://jsperf.com/round-down-to-nearest

Comment: @allicarn missing my solution :(

Comment: @juvian you can edit it - I must've missed it. Sorry!

Comment: @allicarn never used the site, but I guess its like this: http://jsperf.com/round-down-to-nearest/2

Comment: @allicarn: Are you sure that's testing what you think it's testing? I could swear it's testing the time it takes to *create* the function. I took a stab: http://jsperf.com/round-down-to-nearest-again

Comment: ah, @T.J.Crowder you might be right!  Nice catch :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so mine is faster? Seems weird :P

Comment: @juvian: Doesn't seem weird to me, the remainder operator is exactly what I'd reach for for this, not least because `%` and `Math.min` can be **really** optimized by the JIT if they're critical path. (Not that it's likely that performance of this operation matters.) Ray and I were just goofin'. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do this:

```
var adjustNumberOfProducts = function(number) {

    return Math.min(number - (number% 3),9);
}
```

You substract from the number its remainder of the division by 3, forcing it to be a multiple of 3, and then take the min between 9 for your higher values

Comment: @JLRishe faster depends on how broswer manages these kind of operations, but its much clearer and in my browser it runs 3-5 times faster:
http://jsfiddle.net/nb2ru0rm/

Answer (score 1):

You can use some simple math to get this output:

```js
function adjust( number ) {
    return Math.min(Math.floor(number / 3) * 3, 9);
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  document.write('For '+ i +': '+ adjust(i) + '<br>');
```

Edit: Handle max case of 9.

Edit: A note on speed.

While the code above has more operations applied per call to `adjust`, it has fewer execution paths.  The `switch` statement has 9 different paths of execution for the compiler to consider, while a single math flow can be compiled down to faster, native code (using JIT compilers)

Comment: This does not handle the default case `n > 9`. Maybe `Math.max(n, 9)`

Comment: Dope, added it in.  Math.min would be needed, not max.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `i < 9 ? i - i % 3 : 9` to get your values.

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    document.write(i + ' ' + (i < 9 ? i - i % 3 : 9) + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: but it is without the overhead of `Math.min`.